# como pasarle datos al controlador desde la vista laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una vista en `blade`, con una tabla, que a través de un método, me carga mediante un `foreach` todos los datos de la base de datos, que son solicitudes, esas solicitudes tienen que ser aprobadas(cambiando el campo de la base de datos aceptado, a 1) o denegadas, lo cual eliminaría la solicitud sin mas, mi problema viene en que no soy capaz de pasar al controlador los parámetros necesarios para que actualice la solicitud y desaparezca, he probado distintas formas y visto muchos posts , pero ningún se adecua exactamente a lo que yo pretendo hacer, aquí les pongo el código:

**Vista:**

```
 @if($vacations)
                  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered scrolling-dataTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                       <th>Nombre</th>
                       <th>Tipo</th>
                       <th>Fecha inicio</th>
                       <th>Fecha fin</th>
                       <th>Observaciones</th>
                       <th>Pendiente</th>
                       <th>Aprobar</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach ($vacations as $vacation)
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ $vacation->name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $vacation->type }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $vacation->date_from }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $vacation->date_to }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $vacation->observations }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $vacation->aceptado }}</td>

                        <td>  <!-- Single button definir boton para aprobar vacaciones -->
                        <div role="group" class="btn-group">
                          <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-right"><i class="icon-cog3 icon-left"></i> Settings</button>
                          <div aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="{{ url ('/vacation/aceptado',[$vacation->id]) }}" class="dropdown-item">Aprobar</a>
                            <a href="{{url('/vacation/deny')}}" class="dropdown-item">Denegar</a></div>
                          </div>
                         </div>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               @endforeach
```

**Controlador:**

```
 public function update(Request $request, Vacation $vacations)
{
     $this->validate($request, [
        'aceptado' => 'required',
    ]);
    //$inputs=Input::all();
    //$vacation = new Vacation();
    $vacation=Vacation::findOrFail($id);
    $vacation-> aceptado = '1';
    //$vacation-> id = $inputs['id'];

    $vacation->save();

    Mail::send("correo.solicitud", $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->to('email','user')
        ->subject("Respuesta a su solicitud");
    });

    return redirect('/vacation/calendar');

}
```

y la ruta:

```
 Route::post('/vacation/update', 'VacationController@update')->name('aceptado');
```

cuando le doy al botón para aceptar la solicitud me devuelve:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: no entiendo en la linea del controlador "public function update(Request $request, Vacation $vacations)" esto Vacation $vacations y despues "$vacation=Vacation::findOrFail($id);" de donde sacas la variable $id?? deberia ser public function update(Request $request, $id)

Comment: LO he corregido segun me dijo Dev. Joel tal cual su respuesta, gracias por contestar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque no encuentra una ruta con esa `URL` , como estás definiendo la ruta con `name` al final, puedes hacer uso de esta pero le hace falta pasarle el parámetro `$id` a la ruta , Al hacer `click` en el enlace , este se envía por `GET` , y no por `POST`, debería cambiar el verbo desde la ruta.

```
Route::get('/vacation/update/{id}', 'VacationController@update')->name('aceptado');
```

En tu vista llamarías a esta ruta , con el helper route pasando el parámetro, nombre de ruta y el `$id`

```
<a href="{{ route('aceptado',$vacation->id)}}"
         class="dropdown-item">Aprobar</a>
```

Y en tu controlador deberías recibir este `Id` como segundo parámetro

```
public function update(Request $request,$id) {...}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronto comentario, lo he probado pero basicamente me sigue diciendo lo mismo NotFoundHtttpException

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez actualicé mi respuesta, tiene que cambiar el verbo de la ruta, verifique  3:)

Comment: gracias por la correcion, lo he probado y nada sigue igual

Comment: Haga un `dd($id)` en el controlador, llega el valor? Lo he probado localmente y funciona, llega el id al controlador.

Comment: me salta directamente al error, no tengo manera de visualizar ese dd, sera posible que en local se me haya quedado enganchado el xampp?(es el que uso, y es por decirlo de alguna manera..)

Comment: No lo creo. Está seguro que Le está dando click a botón correcto?, la segunda ruta no está definida. ¿Se muestra la vista? O ahí ya se muestra el error

Comment: si, cuando clico en el boton aceptar, la ruta es vacation/update/2 (en el caso del id que selecciono) osea que creo yo que el id lo esta cojiendo bien, pero no se porque no me redirecciona a la vista que deberia ir, aunque lo mande al home 
vista: 
<a href="{{ route('aceptado',$vacation->id)}}" class="dropdown-item">Aprobar</a>
ruta: Route::get('/vacation/update/{$id}', 'VacationController@update')->name('aceptado');

la ruta a la que me manda en el navegador seria esta: http://localhost:8000/vacation/update/2 con lo cual, no entiendo porque no va bien

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez algo se nos está pasando. el código de mi respuesta ha sido probado, si no funciona hay algo que escapa de mis posibilidades solucionar sin más detalles.

Comment: he hecho un par de pruebas, y finalmente he conseguido que no me arrojara ningún error, tenía un "$" por ahi metido que me estaba fastidiando. La ruta ya esta correcta y no da ningun error, pero sigue sin actualizarme en la base de datos, supongo que sera culpa de lo que tengo en el método, que basicamente es lo que tengo arriba, pero añadi el $id en el encabezado y aun asi no hace el update, alguna idea? Muchas gracias por todo :)

Answer (score 2):

El metodo correcto para el update deberia de ser PUT

```
Route::put('/vacation/{id}', 'VacationController@update')->name('aceptado');
```

En Blade , el formulario debe de tener tanto el CRSF y el verbo correcto PUT

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => ['/vacation/update'], 'method' => 'PUT', 'class' =>'form-horizontal')) !!}

{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Y en el controlador

```
public function update(Request $request,$id) {...}
```

Comment: Hola Unai. Una respuesta con muy buen formato ^^  Recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y llevarte otra medalla. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias @lois6b, estoy intentando aprender ha usar esto.

Comment: Lo probare unai muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia, saludos!

Comment: @UnaiSusperregi he probado a añadirlo, pero sigue sin funcionarme, como le comentaba a Dev Joel debo de tener algún problema en el método del controlador.