# Laravel, pasar parametros desde la vista al controlador

Tags: laravel

Tengo una vista con dos botones que trae los pedidos de la BD. El Boton1 trae los pedidos en estado ACTIVOS (CODESTADO=1) y el Boton2 trae los pedidos con estado CERRADOS (CODESTADO=0).

Lo que tengo armado es lo siguiente:

Vista

```
<a href="{{ route('pedidos.activos') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-succcess" target="_blank">Activos</a>
<a href="{{ route('pedidos.cerrados') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-succcess" target="_blank">Cerrados</a>
```

Archivo Rutas Web

```
Route::get('pedidos/activos','PedidosController@activos')->name('pedidos.activos');
Route::get('pedidos/cerrados','PedidosController@cerrados')->name('pedidos.cerrados');
```

El controlador:

```
class PedidosController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function activos(){
        \Log::info('Ingresó Activos (1)');
        
    }

    public function cerrados(){
        \Log::info('Ingresó Cerrados (0)');         
    }
}
```

Dado que ambos métodos ejecutarán la misma query a la BD, con la única diferencia del filtro where codestado, 1 o 0, es que he tratado de que sea un sólo método del controlador que se encargue de aquello, pero necesito pasarle como parámetro el codestado que debe usar para uno u otro botón. Algo así como:

Controlador:

```
public function pedidos(Request $request){

    $opcion=$request;

    if($opcion==1){
        \Log::info('Ingresó Activos (1)');
    }else{
        \Log::info('Ingresó Cerrados (0)');
    }
}
```

El problema es que he intentado enviar el parámetro en la vista, pero no funciona; entiendo que está mal lo que implemento en la vista o está mal en el archivo de rutas o es una combinación de ambos o simplemente no se puede hacer lo que planteo:

Archivo de rutas:

```
Route::get('pedidos/{$op}','PedidosController@pedidos')->name('pedidos.pedidos');
```

Vista:

```
<a href="{{ route('pedidos.pedidos','1') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-succcess" target="_blank">Activos</a>
<a href="{{ route('pedidos.pedidos','0') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-succcess" target="_blank">Cerrados</a>
```

Al ejecutar, me arroja el mensaje:

404
Not Found

Agradezco cualquier comentario que me ayude a resolver el problema.

Con respecto a la línea:

\Log::info();

La utilizo para imprimir un mensaje en el Log de laravel (storage/logs/laravel.log) y así verificar si va sucediendo lo que espero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba de está forma: `{{ route('pedidos.pedidos', ['op' => '1']) }}` y así en ambas rutas

Comment: Hola, me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: pedidos.pedidos] [URI: pedidos/{$op}]. (View: D:\laragon\www\siged\resources\views\home.blade.php) 

Será porque la ruta tiene nombre?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [como pasarle datos al controlador desde la vista laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134826/como-pasarle-datos-al-controlador-desde-la-vista-laravel)

Comment: @JuncoFuerte el parámetro en la URL no se declara con símbolo de pesos, en el método `pedidos` te hace falta recibir separado por coma el parámetro por ejemplo en la variable `$op` y esa es la que usarás dentro del condicional

Comment: @BetaM, muchas gracias por tu comentario. Con tus observaciones, pude lograr lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: Genial, pero en vez de editar la pregunta para añadir la respuesta, ponlo como respuesta!! Luego podrás aceptarla y así todos los usuarios que tengan el mismo problema podrán ver la solución

Answer (score 0):

Con el aporte de @BetaM, pude solucionar el problema y quedó de la siguiente forma:

VISTA:

```
<a href="{{ route('pedidos.pedidos',['op' => '1']) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-succcess" target="_blank">Activos</a>
<a href="{{ route('pedidos.pedidos',['op' => '0']) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-succcess" target="_blank">Cerrados</a>
```

RUTAS:

```
Route::get('pedidos/{op}','PedidosController@pedidos')->name('pedidos.pedidos');
```

CONTROLADOR:

```
public function pedidos(Request $request, $op){

    $opcion=$op;

    if($opcion==1){
        \Log::info('Ingresó Activos (1)');
    }else{
        \Log::info('Ingresó Cerrados (0)');
    }
}
```